# can't fetch rest result on angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying fetch data via REST with angular 2 HttpClient

***basket.component.ts***

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.cart = this.shoppingCartService.get();
    this.cartSubscription = this.cart.subscribe((cart) => {
           this.itemCount = cart.items
              .map((x) => x.quantity)
              .reduce((p, n) => p + n, 0);

           this.cartItems = cart.items.map((item) => {
              let product = {};
              product = this.productsService.find_p(item.productId);
              return {...item,product}
           });
    });
}
```

***basket.component.html***

```
  <tbody *ngIf='cartItems'>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of cartItems">
      <td>
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true" (click)='removeItem(item.productId)' style="font-size: 21px;color:red;"></i>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img class="uk-preserve-width uk-border-circle" src="assets/images/fish.png" width="40" alt="">
      </td>
      <td class="uk-table-link">
        <a class="uk-link-reset" *ngIf='item.product.product' href="">{{ item.product.product.name }}</a>
      </td>
      <td class="uk-text-nowrap">{{ item.quantity }}</td>
      <td class="uk-text-nowrap">۲۵۰۰۰ هزارتومان</td>
      <td class="uk-text-nowrap">ZF-3268</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

but i cant fetch result i think my callback data is text not json but i dont know how to fix it

on inspect element

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'product' of undefined

product log

> product
>   : Observable operator : CatchOperator {selector: ƒ, caught:
>   Observable} source : Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable,
>   operator: MapOperator}
>   _isScalar : false
>   **proto** : Object

and my product service

```
 find_p(id) {
    let url: string = `${this.BASE_URL}/product/${id}.json`;
    return this.http.get(url, {headers: this.headers}).map((res:Response) => res.json() as [{}] )
    //...errors if any
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

When I did that the .json() method was been resolved but another error popped up that

***Property results does not exist on type Promise or observable***

Comment: your `this` inside the `subscribe` might not be referring to the component. Create a variable outside for `this` and use it in `subscribe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue with your code** is `find_p` returning `Observable` not the product data

```
product = this.productsService.find_p(item.productId);
```

And you are using `product` as data on template side.

**Solution :**

Replace this code block

```
this.cartItems = cart.items.map((item) => {
    let product = {};
    product = this.productsService.find_p(item.productId);
    return {...item,product}
});
```

With :

```
let observerArray = [];
cart.items.forEach((item) => {
    observerArray.push(this.productsService.find_p(item.productId));
});

Observable.forkJoin(observerArray).subscribe(products => {
   this.cartItems = cart.items.map((item,index) => {
        return {...item,product : products[index]}
    });
});
```

Comment: @mohammadmahmoodi , Glad to know , Happy coding :)